# bindIP on CentOS for MongoDB process exited with error code

Tags: mongodb, centos

I'm editing a `mongod.conf` file to try and add a specific IP to be able to access the database with.

From what I've read I just need to edit this one file and add a second entry to `bindIp`

Like so:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 11.222.333.44
```

Then save, close and run `sudo systemctl restart mongod`

Only when I run the restart I run into:

> Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

But when I run `mongo` I'm able to connect to the mongo shell locally but unable to connect remotely as the IP binding failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to connect locally, you are most likely connecting to an old process which means either:

- process restart didn't work in that it failed to terminate the old process
- your configuration is invalid, and restart process identified this and stopped
- you have a `mongod` process running on the default port that you started manually and systemd can't stop it

Verify:

1. your configuration is correct
2. you don't have any `mongod` processes running

Then (re)start again.

Also, review the logs using the commands indicated.

Comment: So when I add the new additional IP and run restart I get that error message. When I remove the additional IP the restart command works without any issues or error messages